# Blazor - Virtualize card deck stuck in infinite loop

Tags: blazor, virtualization, blazor-webassembly

I'm working on a .NET6 Blazor webassembly project, and I have a component which display a large amout of cards with a bootstrap4 Card deck layout.

I would like to use the Virtualize component to speed up the rendering, but the card-deck seems to interfere with the virtual height calculation and it gets stuck in an infinite loop.

```
<div class="cards-contanier">
    <div class="card-deck">
        <Virtualize Items="@collection">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title : @context</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                    <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Virtualize>
    </div>
</div>
```

with the cards-container style :

```
.cards-contanier {
  height: 50vh;
  border: solid black 1px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  scrollbar-color: red transparent;
}
```

PS : It happens also with a simple display:flex instead of the card-deck

I have made a fully expample you can found here : https://github.com/Rizov74/BlazorVirtualizeCardDeck/blob/master/BlazorVirtualizeCardDeck/Pages/Index.razor

Have you some workaround ? My cards can take up to 5sec to display.
I'm not forced to use the bootstrap card-deck script.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are the heights of each and every card _exactly the same_?  (Given your examples, I'm guessing not)  If not, you can't use `<Virtualize>`.  (This is an extremely frustrating limitation of `Virtualize` -- upvote the [github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/25058) if this is affecting you.)

Comment: @KirkWoll The heights are not exactly the same, but I can fix the height it's not a problem. However how the Virtualize component knows how many cards there is in a row? If I reduce my screen width, it has no clue there is one less card by rows.